# Normal of pointcloud2

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am a beginner un ros. I want to find the normal of my pointcloud2. Is there a class who do that un ros?
Thanks you un avance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277194/normal-of-pointcloud2/) by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the point cloud storage and manipulation in ROS is actually done using the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/), so this is what you'll use to calculate the normals of your point cloud.

There's a good page here which describes some of the theory of normal estimation from point clouds, as well as a worked example using the point cloud library.

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php

This should get you moving in the right direction.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2